# Why does QtCreator complain about missing <algorithm>

Tags: c++, algorithm, ubuntu-14.04, qt-creator

I can't compile anything in QtCreator - not even a standard QWidget example application. On compilation I get:`/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:82: error: algorithm: No such file or directory` and it sets the cursor toline 82 in `global.h` at `#include <algorithm>` - why is this, what is missing on this machine?
**UPDATE:**
What I did: I created a project using QtCreator on another computer which works & compiles fine. I copied it to this one, tried to start it but get an error:`: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_              3.4.21' not found (required by`- hence I then tried to recompiled it with the provided Makefile but I get a whole buch of errors (pages or errors). So My intention was to fire up`QtCreator` and see if i can compile it from within but no dough due to the above error....What's going on and how do I get things back in order?

Comment: [`<algorithm>` is a standard header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). Your compiler setup is broken. The easiest way to fix that is to use the maintenance tool to install a compiler. If you insist on using MSVC you will have to do some digging to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @nwp: I see nothing here to suggest use of MSVC. Rather the contrary, the `/usr/include/` would tend to suggest a Unix variant.

Comment: @nwp I'm not using MSVC, I'm on `Ubuntu Linux`... is there a good maintenance tool you know about?

Comment: The maintenance tool is part of Qt's package when you install it [using the installer](https://www1.qt.io/download/). If you installed Qt Creator it via apt then it generally isn't included, so ignore that. In theory the package manager should have set up everything for you. You can try if you can compile a program from command line and then check Projects->Manage Kits and see if there are paths wrong.

Comment: @nwp please see my updated question above... does that make a bit more sense now?

Comment: @nwp `Projects -> Manage Kits` is empty, it only says `Auto-detected` and then under it is says `Manual - Desktop (default)` + under `cmake`, the `Executable:` field is empty... but `cmake` is installed: `which cmake` gives me `/usr/bin/cmake`

Comment: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` on my system is part of the package `libstdc++6` so maybe you should install that along with `g++-6`. Does the `Desktop (default)` kit have a field `Compiler C++ GCC in /usr/bin` or something similar and does `/usr/bin/g++ --version` print something reasonable?

Comment: version: `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`

Comment: there is not `g++-6' package and I already have `libstdc++6`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156056/discussion-between-cerr-and-nwp).